# System.ArgumentException: Column 'post' does not belong to table Table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am  getting   error at line no  34. I have also a table in database with column post

```
Line 32:             Label5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["date_of_birth"].ToString();
Line 33:           
Line 34:             Label8.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["post"].ToString();
Line 35:             Label7.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["subjects"].ToString();
Line 36:             Label6.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Score"].ToString();
**strong text**
```

Comment: Debug and FInd what query is building inside the Code. Execute the same Query in SSMS. So that you can find it on your own.

Comment: it would be great if you include the code that you are using to populate the DataSet `dt`, or the query that you are using to fetch the data

Answer (score 1):

There's a 90% chance that you just got the capitalization wrong.

Check if your column is actually named `Post` and try this code:

```
Line 34:             Label8.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Post"].ToString();
```

To avoid an exception for tables that may or may not contain this column, you can check for the presence of this column dynamically:

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("post"))
    //do something
```